# How to hide my tabs until a condition is met

Tags: javascript, html

I have a clicker game basically done but i want to hide my tabs until rebirths is equal to a certain amount.

I have tried following the same format i have for hideing buttons but my tabs dont really have ids.

html code for 2 pages:

```
    <html>

   <head>
        <title> Basic Clicker</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>

<body>
    <div class="nav_bar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="GameMainWindow.html" id="onlink">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="SkillTree.html">SkillTree</a></li>
        <li><a href="Equipment.html">Equipment</a></li>
        <li><a href="Pets.html">Pets</a></li>
        <li><a href="Skills.html">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="Quests.html">Quests</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="main_container">
    <p>
        <html>

        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="interface.css" />
        </head>
        <title> Basic Clicker</title>
```

2nd page:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>

<head>
   <title> Basic Clicker</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>

   <body>
    <div class="nav_bar">
        <ul>
              <li><a href="GameMainWindow.html">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="SkillTree.html">SkillTree</a></li>
              <li><a href="Equipment.html">Equipment</a></li>
              <li><a href="Pets.html">Pets</a></li>
              <li><a href="Skills.html" id="onlink">Skills</a></li>
               <li><a href="Quests.html">Quests</a></li>
       </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="main_container">
    <p>
        <html>

        <head>
            <title>HTML div</title>
        </head>

        <body>
            <div style="width: 300px;float:left; border: 15px solid green; height:300px; background:white; margin:10px" class="col-sm-5">
                &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Inventory
                <br />
                <span id="BronzeOre">
                    Bronze: <span id="Bronze">0</span>
                    <br />
                </span>

                <span id="SilverOre">
                    Silver: <span id="Silver">0</span>
                    <br />
                </span>

                <span id="GoldOre">
                    Gold: <span id="Gold">0</span>
                    <br />
                </span>

                <span id="DiamondOre">
                    Diamond: <span id="Diamond">0</span>
                    <br />
                </span>
```

example of javascript I used to hide buttons/lines:

```
var SilverOre = document.getElementById('SilverOre');
var GoldOre = document.getElementById('GoldOre');
var DiamondOre = document.getElementById('DiamondOre');



 function checkUnlockOre() {
      if (Mininglv >= 10) {
            SilverOre.style.visibility = 'visible'
        } else {
           SilverOre.style.visibility = 'hidden'
      }
    if (Mininglv >= 20) {
        GoldOre.style.visibility = 'visible'
   } else {
       GoldOre.style.visibility = 'hidden'
   }
    if (Mininglv >= 30) {
        DiamondOre.style.visibility = 'visible'
    } else {
        DiamondOre.style.visibility = 'hidden'
    }
```

I expect the 2nd page  to stay hidden( the rest of the pages) until a condition is met. But at the moment none of my pages are hidden causing the player to have everything unlocked at the start.

Comment: You have `<html>` and `<head>` tags all over the place and nothing that really looks like a "tab".  Please clean up your code and comment it to give a clear indication of what you mean by "tab"

Comment: <li><a href="GameMainWindow.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="SkillTree.html" id="onlink">SkillTree</a></li>
        <li><a href="Equipment.html">Equipment</a></li>
        <li><a href="Pets.html">Pets</a></li>
        <li><a href="Skills.html">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="Quests.html">Quests</a></li>

Comment: these are my different tabs http://prntscr.com/nzfw7f

Comment: Use the "edit" link below the question to the left and put your code in the question itself please.  A picture of some tabs with no HTML is useless.  (Do you also go to a mechanic to get them to fix your car without taking the car?)

Comment: I was showing what i ment by "tabs" sorry you asked what i meant by tabs

Answer (score 0):

Elements you're getting in JS is missing from HTML you shared, share the full html to understand it better.
I don't see document.getElementById('SilverOre') in HTML for example.

Comment: ah I get ya. thats a diffrent tab. ill link that one. its just the name of the id.

Comment: I was looking for anyway to hide them posted that example to show what i did to hide the Ore id spans. I'm not sure how to name/ format the tabs to be able to do that

Comment: At the beginning of the JS, make other tabs visibility hidden. Also make sure, you have no console errors.

Comment: ? i dont have the tabs in a javascript. they are all different html files. how do i format the html to make them be  able to be hidden

Comment: Are we talking about navigation menu bar or tabs? Two are different.

Comment: Either of the cases, hide the items by default to make it visible based on your condition.

Comment: i posted this question to ask how to. i don't understand how to sigh If i knew how to do that i would already have done that. how do you hide them then unhide them based on a condition.

Comment: You can add inline css to set visibility hidden or from JS set visibility of element hidden, I am unable to write code sample as I am replying from mobile. Also, I asked about console errors.

Comment: <li><a href="GameMainWindow.html">Home</a>  is there a way i can give this a id

Comment: You can give ID to list or anchor tag like, <li id='id1'> and you can apply inline CSS like <li style="visibility: hidden">

Comment: oh sweet thanks. yea that was my biggest issue figure out how to name them. I will try this now

Comment: I got this so far http://prntscr.com/nzgsrc  http://prntscr.com/nzgsuw  but this isnt working. how would i go about hideing it in the first place then turning that off if rebirths>=1

Comment: if u can still help me i still dont have a working way to have unlockable tabs